# How to add inset box-shadow to image?

Tags: html, css

Basically, I want sort of a sunken-in effect on an image, as is shown for the outer div in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sK5bB/32/

Here's my CSS from the Fiddle (it only works for div, not image):

```
#outerDiv {    
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 10px #555;
}
```

Comment: That's because the shadow sits behind the image. You either need to wrap it in another element or use a `background-image` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For image you'll need to overlap it with a DIV (or SPAN) element with that box-shadow.

<sub>pseudo-code:</sub>

```
<common container>
    <image>
    <shadow>
</common container>
```

You can use the pseudo `:after` to create the shadowed element:

```css
.imageStyler{
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:5px;
}
.imageStyler img{
 vertical-align:middle;
}
.imageStyler:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 10px #555;
}
```

```html
    <span class="imageStyler">
        <img src="//placehold.it/100x100/f0f">
    </span>
```

Yes, sadly, if you ingenuously thought about it: `img:after` will not work.

Answer (score -1):

What about an inset border ? [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sK5bB/33/)

```
border:7px inset grey;border-radius:5px;
```

```css
#outerDiv {    
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 10px #555;
}
#imgimg{border:7px inset grey;border-radius:5px;}
```

```html
<div id="outerDiv"></div>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" id="imgimg"/>
```